# Проверить наличие таблицы в базе данных?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Добрый День, Задача такова проверить наличие таблицы в базе данных максимально простым методом и не в коем случае не загружая процесс! Я гуглил но на форумах кроме как

```
SELECT * from 'table_name'
```

ничего посоветовать толком не могут либо совсем уж огроменные конструкции в 10 строк, не ужели нету в php простой команды типа

```
$yes = estlitablicav($database,$tablename);
if ($yes == FALSE) { echo "Такой таблицы тут отродясь не было!"; }
```

если нет такого варианта то я воспользуюсь вещами с формов, зарание спасибо!

Comment: я имею в виду есть ли с sql или php встроенная функция проверки! вот такое я и сам своять могу function mysql_table_seek($tablename, $dbname) {
    $table_list = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES FROM `".$dbname."`");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($table_list)) {
        if ($tablename==$row[0]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

Comment: Здравствуйте. Может Вам подойдёт мой ответ, который я оставил ниже. Если нет, напишите в комментарии, я его удалю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выборка из таблицы может приводить к ошибочному срабатыванию, если таблица пустая.

Мой выбор — `SHOW TABLES` при обязательном использовании подготовки (prepare) запросов во избежание sql-инъекций, если исходное имя таблицы хранится в переменной. Псевдокод, возможны опечатки — не протестировал, лишь пишу логику.

```
function isTableExists($dbLink, $tableName){
  if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbLink, "SHOW TABLES LIKE '?';")) {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $tableName);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $unused_result);
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
  }
  return ( mysqli_affected_rows($dbLink) > 0);
}
```

То, что обычно подобные запросы занимают много строк, на мой взгляд, связано как раз-таки с проблемами, вызванными возможными sql-инъекциями. Если Вы не знаете что это такое, просто набейте в Google.

Answer (score 5):

Зачем же делать выборку, когда список таблиц доступен.

```
SHOW TABLES FROM 'db_name' LIKE 'нужная_таблица';
```

В PHP это проверить можно так:

```
$query = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES FROM 'db_name' LIKE 'нужная_таблица';");
$result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
```

И далее уже обрабатываете результаты.

Answer (score 2):

Это вы какие-то неправильные форумы смотрите.

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 1; -- тоже не самое хорошее решение.
```

Делайте выборку из information_schema или

```
SHOW TABLES FROM `db_name` like 'table_name';
```

Comment: да много гед советовали только пока не разобрался как фильтровать возвращаемый парметр запускаю то его я так `$ex = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES FROM `literuture` LIKE 'imgcheck'");` и эхо $ex выдет мне Resourse #id5 тоесть он возвращает переменную типа РЕСКРС а это Resource это - специальная переменная, содержащая ссылку на внешний ресурс. при том он возвращает и при наличии таблицы и при отсутствии

Comment: не могу к стати найти документацию по SHOW TABLES FROM [тут](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/SHOW_DATABASE_INFO.html)

Comment: фильтровать через mysql_fetch_assoc

Comment: документация http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-tables.html

Answer (score 2):

Просто нужно проверить, чтобы следующий запрос вернул одну строку

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE 'table_name'
```

Answer (score 2):

[Проверка таблицы и не толко на существование](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/check-table.html)

Пример:

```
CHECK TABLE tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд самый лучший метод таков

```
$exs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 1");
```

простой селект, а `LIMIT` - позволит не грузить сильно сервер, если кто найдет лучше и самое главное проще то думаю тут и ответят, а пока буду и дальше тогда юзать такую конструкцию пока не найдется альтернатива

Comment: Лучше $exs = mysql_query("SELECT 1 FROM table LIMIT 1");

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT IF(COUNT(*)>0, 'Yes', 'No') AS Existance 
FROM `information_schema`.`TABLES` 
WHERE 1 AND `TABLE_NAME`= 'table_name'
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]